# cannot display data got via AJAX call in another view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have dynamically created link on my view.

```
var get_list = '<a href="#" name="'+country+'" class="get_list">Get List</a>';
```

When I click on it, it gets the list from database via AJAX call and displays it. Now I want it to display that list in **another view** but I do not have an idea how can I do it. I changed it in the below mentioned way but it did not work. Could you please help me to solve the problem.

```
var get_list = '<a href="http://localhost/abc/cont/get_list" 
    name="'+country+'" class="get_list">Get List</a>';
```

**here is my controller:**

```
public function get_list() {
//some code here
$country = $this->input->post('country');                        
if ($this->model_users->did_get_list($country)) {               
$data["results"]= $this->model_users->did_get_list($country);                   
echo json_encode($data);            
$this->load->view("view_list"); //loads the second view         
}
else {              
$data = array('message' => "Could not load the list.");
echo json_encode($data);
$this->load->view("view_list"); //loads the second view
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second parameter to supply the view with a variable(s)

```
$vars = array();
$vars['var1'] = 'My variable 1';
$vars['json'] = $data;
$this->load->view('view_list', $vars);
```

Now in your view you can use the variables names (array indexes) as variables:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $var1;?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $json;?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

See more info in the official [Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Comment: I tried in that way you described but it did not work. Please check my question, I have inserted an image. You suggest to pass the data from controller to the second view (red arrow). But I guess data should be passed with JS file as it is the AJAX call.

Comment: So when you say JS (the second box) you mean you are requesting the controller with Ajax request?